# Download file from url as attachment

Tags: php, attachment, force-download

I am unable to set proper headers to download file from URL.
Below code just shows content of URL in browser instead download.

```
$file_name = "image1.jpg";
$content_type = "image/jpeg";
$url = "http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/incgraph/example.jpg";

header('Pragma: public');   // required
header('Expires: 0');       // no cache
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($file_name)).' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: private',false);
header("Content-type: ".$content_type);
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name);
header("Location: ".$url);
exit(0);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to fetch the content of `example.jpg` and passthru to the browser. `Location: ` headers will simply redirect the user.

Comment: Thanks @BenM for reply. But I do not have to download image in my server.

Comment: @GuruGGulab — You are wrong. You do if you want to add your own HTTP headers to it.

Comment: I need to download file direct from URL instead showing in browser. If my code is wrong then please suggest me another solution. My requirement is to allow user to download external URL file instead showing in browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
$originalPath = $_REQUEST['path'];  //path with filename
$fileName = $_REQUEST['fileName'];  // filename for downloaded file name    
if (file_exists($originalPath)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($fileName));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($originalPath));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($originalPath);
    exit;
} else {
    echo 'FILE_NOT_FOUND';
}
```

Comment: I have only URL not absolute path of file. I have to use URL not actual location of file. URL is external source not from my server, I do not have actual path for that file.

Answer (score 0):

this code is work fine to download from url :

```
set_time_limit(0);

//File to save the contents to
$fp = fopen ('file.type', 'w+');

$url = "http://yoursite.come/file.type";

//Here is the file we are downloading, replace spaces with %20
$ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);

//give curl the file pointer so that it can write to it
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);//get curl response

//done
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Above code will download file in my server and I do not have to download file into my server space. I have to give that file direct to user to download in his/her PCs / Laptops.

Answer (score 0):

using this code you can save image in our server and you can download image using my upper code.

```
file_put_contents("Tmpfile.jpg", fopen("http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/incgraph/example.jpg", 'r'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Download file from url(in list) and save the file with last name of the url using python**

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
import re,os
for url in open('C:\\Users\\SRINU\\Desktop\\Election_pdfs_urls\\33.txt'):
  possible_urls = re.findall(r'(https?://[^\s]+)', url)
  for links in possible_urls:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(links.format(url.encode('utf-8')))
    filename_w_ext = os.path.basename(links)
    file = open(filename_w_ext, 'wb')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()
```